# Trying to read an old hard drive: "One of the USB devices attached to the computer has malfunctioned"

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, usb

I have an old external hard drive that was formatted NTFS (If I recall correctly) using a Windows XP machine. The drive stayed in storage for years, and I'm trying to read files off of it with a Windows 7 Desktop computer. The drive powers up, but when I connect it to the machine via USB I receive the following error message:

```
One of the USB devices attached to the computer has malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it

Unknown USB Device
```

The Windows machine that I'm using does not currently have internet available, but I could transfer things using a thumb drive if need be. I'm just not sure where to start troubleshooting this. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you have the XP disc try: put it in and then "update the driver" and point the driver to the i386 folder. Try: google to see if the model enclosure requires an XP driver. Also, check the drive manager applet, and if you see the drive there, apply a drive letter to it that is outside the "normal range" like `q:`. bear in mind, most enclosures contain a normal drive with an adapter attached. you may be able to open the enclosure, remove the drive, and connect it as an internal

Comment: Thanks for those tips! I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure how to point a driver to a specific folder. Could you elaborate on that? And could you let me know how to access the drive manager applet? Thanks again!

Comment: drive manager is a control panel applet, possibly via admin options, cannot recall. update driver is via "device manager" also via control panel. If it needs a driver, you should see the USB enclosure in the list with an exlamation point next to it. Look at that device and look for "update driver" or something similar, and then look for a "have disc" button.